# convert int to string which only contains lowercase letters and numbers and back (python)

Tags: python, string, int

python 2.7

how do you take any number and be able to compress it to just lowercase letters and numbers? and how do you take the resulting string and put it back to the number?

doing something like chr() for each block of numbers of 3 numbers won't work because if the block of number is bigger than 255, it will throw an error, and I only want lowercase numbers and letters.

edit:

the main purpose of this it to compress a number. the user will be seeing this and will be typing it in, so it needs to be easily typeable (can't have weird characters that ascii supports but isn't on a standard keyboard)

Comment: Provide a sample usage? I.e. what's the input and the expected output of this operation?

Comment: I think only uppercase letters would be better than only lowercase. Both have about the same number of collisions (e.g., l=1, O=0), but lowercase letters vary much more in height, making it harder to keep your place when typing it in. That's why most anti-piracy auth codes use uppercase.

Comment: Also, most people don't use base-36, because of those collisions. Of course the details depend on your font, but it's usually best to skip at least I and O (for uppercase) or l and o (for lowercase). Still, the principle of using base-36 (as F.J. shows below) is the same, it's just base-34, and it should take a matter of minutes to change the code.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36), below is an adapted version of the Python implementation that you can find on Wikipedia:

```
def base36encode(number, alphabet='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'):
    """Converts an integer to a base36 string."""
    if not isinstance(number, (int, long)):
        raise TypeError('number must be an integer')

    base36 = '' if number != 0 else '0'
    sign = ''
    if number < 0:
        sign = '-'
        number = -number

    while number != 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, len(alphabet))
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return sign + base36

def base36decode(number):
    return int(number, 36)

>>> print base36encode(1412823931503067241)
aqf8aa0006eh
>>> print base36decode('aqf8aa0006eh')
1412823931503067241
```

Comment: +1. You should mention the upper and lower methods on strings as the way to adapt it, so it's clear just how not difficult it is.

Comment: Never mind the above comment—your edit means he no longer has to call base36encode(n).lower().

Comment: @QxQ: You could make the result even easier to type by using a smaller alphabet like just the letters on the home row of on a QWERTY keyboard, although it would likely be more to type.

Answer (score 0):

`str.lower()` makes a string str lowercase. Alternatively, you could use [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to only find letters/words and numbers, but the question is not very clear, so I'm not sure what you mean.